# using cmake with vs2017, cannot find cmake.exe

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

According to MSDN I should have cmake installed with latest version of vs2017. I have the project type `Visual c++ > CMake`, so I think i have selected all the goodies I need.

But I dont see cmake.exe anywhere. Is there some extra package I need to install?

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe` on my machine

Comment: aha - ok. I Surprised that it didnt get added to my path when I open 'vs command shell'

Comment: At the moment the `cmake` coming with VS2017 is a version altered by Microsoft. Until those changes are merged back in to the official `cmake` I think it's a good idea to keep those separated. See also ["Use installed CMake instead of embedded one in Visual Studio 2017?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221297/use-installed-cmake-instead-of-embedded-one-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue today. Path to cmake.exe was not added to PATH environment variable. Had to add it manually. Location for Visual Studio 2019 is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin
```