# Configure CMake version in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to configure the Visual Studio 2019 integrated CMake version? There are features in the latest CMake version that I would like to use, but I'm forced to build from the command line in this case. If I build from the VS IDE, the CMake version used is the Visual Studio-integrated one. I would like to change it if possible.

Comment: If you want to stick with the built-in version, I guess like you can open a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351720/update-the-bundled-cmake-to-version-312.html) about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download the latest CMake from [here](https://cmake.org/download/) to your system. To point Visual Studio to this latest version, you have to edit your [*CMakeSettings.json*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=msvc-160) file. You must change the value of the [`cmakeExecutable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=vs-2019#additional-settings-for-cmake-linux-projects) option to the installed location of the latest CMake version.

CMakeSettings.json:

```
  ...
  "cmakeExecutable": "C:/path/to/new/cmake/executable",
  ...
```

---

If you followed:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-160

Then `CMakeSettings.json` should appear directly in your solution explorer window:

[image]

Comment: This works for Visual Studio generator. If I use Ninja generator VS falls back to the integrated version of cmake.

Comment: @marcks It sounds like that may be a bug in Visual Studio. It may be worth looking for or opening up a new bug report, if that is the case.

Comment: I have reported the problem to the visual studio developers community [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/814128/how-perform-visual-studio-2019-ninja-builds-with-c.html). I have also opened a new question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778775/how-perform-visual-studio-2019-ninja-builds-with-custom-cmake-version)

Comment: @marcks Changing the CMake executable requires regenerating the CMake cache.  Visual Studio won't automatically do that, though.  Select `Project >> Delete Cache and Reconfigure`.

Comment: Hope this works for VS 2019. The given setting was completely ignored in my case in VS 2017.

Comment: Can you provide more information about this CMakeSettings.json file? What is it? Where can we find it?

Comment: @MikeR See the MS reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=msvc-170).

Answer (score 3):

If you are building in VS2019 with `CMakePresets.json` instead of proprietary configs in `CMakeSettings.json`, then I found no other way then replacing the CMake files in VS folder. I had no problems since replacing the files.

They are located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake
```

Should this path not be correct on your machine, you can also see this in the CMake Output window:
[image: VS Output screenshot]

Comment: simplest solution for me too, only difference that I am using the Community version, so path is ... 
 2019\Community ...  
( this is also one of my reasons for migrating to cmake - I am tired of Visual Studio internal configurations and updates )

Answer (score 1):

I myself tried with Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition) and I just had to configure the `VS160COMNTOOLS` variable so that CMake correctly detects Visual Studio.

```
export VS160COMNTOOLS="/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/Tools"
```

(cf https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html)

NB: in my case, in a Travis-CI workflow, I installed Visual Studio using the commands:

```
choco install visualstudio2019community
choco install visualstudio2019-workload-nativedesktop # required
```

With only the first package, CMake detection of VS2019 failed.

Comment: On travis-ci, I would suggest to just install the build tools:

`choco install visualstudio2019buildtools --package-parameters "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64"`

Answer (score 0):

setting `cmakeExecutable` worked for me (vs 2022). I just add another note that the path to cmake executable is machine-specific. If you want to hide it, you can use [Enviroment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=msvc-170#custom-environment-variables). Just create a new environment variable in Windows and reference to it in `CMakeSettings.json`:
[image]

```
...
"cmakeExecutable": "${env.cmake_path}"
...
```