# How perform Visual studio 2019 Ninja builds with custom CMake version?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019, ninja

I'm trying to build a project with Ninja on Visual Studio 2019 from the IDE. I want to use a CMake version different from the one integrated in the VS 2019 distribution. I have set the `cmakeExecutable` variable in my *CMakeSettings.json* file to point to my system installation of CMake and the build works fine using the Visual Studio generator. However, if I use Ninja as generator, Visual Studio falls back using the VS-integrated version of CMake. Is there a way to build with Ninja and a custom CMake version from the IDE?

Comment: I suspect that Microsoft's shipped CMake has patches to make it work there. I would guess the patches are available on [Microsoft's fork](https://github.com/microsoft/CMake/releases), but I'm not seeing anything obvious there.

Comment: @marcks if you pass to CMake -GNinja, the Ninja generator will be used, there is not such mechanism for 'fallback to the Visual Studio generators'. Can you provide all the output in the Output's CMake pane?